Conditional probability of a random walk
Let $X$ be a random loss and $P$ a premium for a insurance company to transfer this risk.
Let us assume that the insurance company chooses a premium equal to the expected loss, so $P=\mathbb{E}(X)$. Now the following example has the intention to show that with this premium the probability of losing any amount of money is $1$.
Let $X$ be a random loss which has the probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ being $2$ and the probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ being $0$. Now the expected loss is $\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{2} \cdot2+\frac{1}{2}\cdot0=1 \end{align*}$.
Now consider multiple insurances as random experiments following one after the other where one gets either $1$ (no loss) or one loses $1$ (loss of $2$ minus premium of $\mathbb{E}(X)=1$).
Let's look at the following conditional probability:
$\begin{align} p=\mathbb{P}(\text{Capital reaches value $K-1$ after a finite time} \mid \text{Initial Capital}= K)\end{align}$.
One gets the following equation
$\begin{align} p\overset{(*)}{=}\mathbb{P}(\text{loss occurs}) + \mathbb{P}(\text{loss does not occur})\cdot p^2\tag{1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot p^2\end{align}$
This quadratic equation only has the solution $p=1$. Therefore, one will almost surely make a loss of $1$ after finite time. Iteration of this approach leads to the fact that for any initial value for the capital $K$ you will lose everything!
(source in german language: https://www.math.tugraz.at/mathc/fvm/VO-Folie-2013-01-16.pdf )


I do not understand the equal sign $(*)$ in the equation $(1)$ above. Furthermore this result seems not intuitive to me. For me this means that if I would go to a casino with a arbitrary amount of money in my pocket and play a game where I get $1\$$ with a probability of  $\frac{1}{2}$  or lose $1\$$ with a probability of  $\frac{1}{2}$, I would lose everything in the long run regardless of what amount of money I have in my pocket in the beginning. I would have thought that in the long run I would win and lose nearly the exact amount of money so there would be no difference and my initial amount of money keeps consistent.
Maybe someone can help. I am searching for a intuitive way of understanding the fact in ruin theory that the expected loss as a premium of a insurance company will almost surely drive the company to ruin regardless of the amount of initial capital.
Thanks in advance!

The simple random walk eventually hits every level with chance $1$ as an alternative proof.
